# How we can call the methods with the help of an array object?

Tags: java, arrays

How can we call the methods with the help of an array object?

for example :

```
class Employee
    {
        int value;

        Employee(int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public void checkValue(int value1, int value2)
        {
            // i want to check here value1 & value2 is there or not in array
            // Or in another word I want to retrieve every element of the array in this method.   
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public static void main(String arg[])
        {
            Employee e1[] = { new Employee(100), new Employee(200), new Employee(300) };

            e1.checkValue(100, 200);

        }
    }
```

So while calling to e1.checkValue(100, 200) I am getting compile time error and I want to call this way only. This question asked me in one of the interviews.

Comment: You can't. Where's that method defined, and what are you expecting?

Comment: Do you want to loop over the array and call the method on each element of it?

Comment: What is `someMethod ` ? or in other words - *what* are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: in side that method i want to read every element of that array object which is calling to any particular method. method can be any method just i gave the example like e1.someMethod();

Comment: Come on now, you can and should improve this question as it is very incomplete and hard to answer. It's like we're having to drag information out of you in dribs and drabs and no one likes to play that game. Please show more *real* code and tell more details of the problem.

Comment: simply `e1[index].someMethod();`will work.

Comment: Seems to me that you are almost asking how to access Employee methods of anonymous objects that are stored in an array. In that case you do it like this:  e1[0].getEmployeeName() or e1[1].setSalary(newSalary).

Comment: I wrote the full program above and this program asked me in one of the interview @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.stream(your array) will give  a stream.
On stream apply a filter method with ur input
Then collect the result using a collector.

This should be the go to way in Java 8.